# TypeScript + React: Enforce that component returns another type of component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Let's say you have a generic component called `<Banner />`:

```
function Banner({ message }: { message: string; }) {
  return <div>{message}</div>;
}
```

And then let's say I want to create `<SuccessBanner />` and `<ErrorBanner />`:

```
function SuccessBanner() {
  return <Banner message="success" />;
}

function ErrorBanner() {
  return <Banner message="error" />;
}
```

How can I use typescript to enforce that both SuccessBanner and ErrorBanner return a `<Banner />` and not anything else? i.e. something like this

```
function SuccessBanner(): <Banner /> {
  // return <div />; // would throw a TS error
  return <Banner message="success" />;
}

function ErrorBanner(): <Banner /> {
  return <Banner message="error" />;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `typeOf Banner` as the return type?

Comment: `typeof Banner` would be the type of the _function_, not the type of an instance of the component itself. Use `React.ReactElement<typeof Banner>`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not ([currently](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699)) possible. The return type of JSX will always be `JSX.Element`, a non generic type.

---

### Explanation

The `JSX` namespace provides types and interfaces that tell TS how to interpret JSX: which elements exist; which properties and can be passed along with their respective types; the shape of component functions and classes; and, most relevant here, the return type of the **JSX Factory Function**.

#### JSX Factory Function

`tsc` has an option named [`jsxFactory`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsxFactory) which takes a `string`. In react, this is set to `React.createElement` (which also happens to be the default value for this property). This property gives the name of a function that is called anytime JSX is used. JSX implementers can leverage this to provide a custom JSX factory function like this oversimplification:

```typescript
// Example for using JSX to create DOM elements:
function jsx(tag: JSX.Tag | JSX.Component, 
             attributes: { [key: string]: any } | null, 
             ...children: Node[]) 
{
    // Handle components:
    if (typeof tag === 'function') {
        return tag(attributes ?? {}, children);
    }
    type Tag = typeof tag;
    const element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag] = document.createElement(tag);

    // ... here we assign properties and add children ...
    
    return element;
}
```

Then all we have to do is set `"jsxFactory": "jsx"` in our tsconfig and import `jsx` in any .tsx file ([see also: Typescript JSX without React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557309/typescript-jsx-without-react/68238924)).

So, it seems like we should be able to do some type inference with generics on our `jsx` function to get specific return types, right?

#### JSX.Element

Wrong. Unfortunately, Typescript takes a bit of a shortcut (something about avoiding compiler slowdowns due to deep nested JSX); rather than infer the return type of JSX using the factory function, Typescript uses the `JSX.Element` type. This type is **not** generic: it can be any one thing:

```typescript
namespace JSX {
  type Element = Node;
}
```

So, what is React's definition of `JSX.Element`?

```typescript
namespace JSX {
    interface Element extends React.ReactElement<any, any> { }
    // ...
```

So every `JSX.Element` will be `React.ReactElement<any, any>`, regardless of elements or components.

In your example, we can verify this like so:

```typescript
type BannerType = ReturnType<typeof Banner>;
// Intellisense: type BannerType = JSX.Element

const div = <div />
type OtherType = typeof div;
// Intellisense: type OtherType = JSX.Element
```

*Note: At the time of writing, Typescript's version is 4.6.2.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation! I was strugling last few hours to understand at which point my ReactElement generic types are lost.

Comment: this is the reason why i do div({ class: "hello" }, [ "Hello" ]) over jsx

Answer (score 0):

Use `React.ReactElement<>`

i.e.

```
function SuccessBanner(): React.ReactElement<typeof Banner> {
  // return <div />; // would throw a TS error
  return <Banner message="success" />;
}

function ErrorBanner(): React.ReactElement<typeof Banner> {
  return <Banner message="error" />;
}
```

Edit: hmm this doesn't seem to be working as I would expect. It seems the value of a component rendered in JSX is `JSX.Element` which unfortunately can not be typed to be a specific component.