# Covariant array of React components

Tags: typescript

I have a class I have derived from a base class, with a union of the base properties and the properties of the component. Something like:

```
interface BaseFooProps {
  name: string;
}
type BaseFoo<T extends BaseFooProps = BaseFooProps> = React.FC<T & BaseFooProps>;
const BaseFooComponent: React.FC<BaseFooProps> = ({ name }) => <>{name}</>;
```

And the derived class:

```
interface AProps extends BaseFooProps {
  height: number;
}
const A: React.FC<AProps> = ...
```

Then, I want to have another component that takes the array of said `BaseFoo` components. This is to enforce that each array member has at least the base properties:

```
interface OtherBarProps {
  items: BaseFoo[]
};

const OtherBar: React.FC<OtherBarProps> = ...

const items = [
  <A name=... height=... key=... />,
];
<OtherBar items={components} />
```

But that last line complains, saying that `Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'BaseFoo<BaseFooProps>[]'`.

I've tried casting `items` with `as ...`, and casting the left-hand side, as well as adding `{}` to the `React.FC<T & BaseFooProps>` definition, but none of these solved the issue.

Why are the array's members cast so generically to `Element`, and not to `BaseFoo`? How do I encourage the type system to accept these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up `Element` and `Component` types. A component instance (element) like `<A/>` is not equivalent to the component function itself `const A = () => {...}`. If you want to pass the actual instances you need to use `React.ReactElement`.

```
interface OtherBarProps {
  items: React.ReactElement<BaseFooProps>[]
  // Or the equivalent of your original type 
  // items: React.ReactElement<React.ComponentProps<BaseFoo>>[]
};

const items = [
  <A name="Joe" height={42} />,
];

<OtherBar items={items} />
```

Unfortunately, it seems the only way to actually restrict what elements are allowed is to go in and explicitly set types for everything you want to use. This is because [all React components currently return the supertype JSX.Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499433/typescript-react-enforce-that-component-returns-another-type-of-component), even if you give them a `React.ReactElement<PropType>` return type.

So you could do something like this:

```
const newA: React.ReactElement<AProps> = <A name="Joe" height={42} />;
const button: React.ReactElement<{}> = <button/>

const items = [
  newA,
  button
];

// Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'BaseFooProps'.
<OtherBar items={items} />
```

Comment: This squashes the error, but it does not restrict the type of element within the `items` array - that is, I can add say `<button key={1} />` to the array and there will be no type error. Is there a way I can restrict the type of elements in the array?

Comment: I’ve accepted the answer, and even if it isn’t satisfyingly restricting the array to element types of the specified base, it is correct by way of resolving my misunderstanding between the element and component types in the array. Thanks!

Comment: @NickBull that's interesting, I didn't realise it would do that. See the edit, hope that helps.